# Flutter back-pressed shows black screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created `NavigationDrawer` in flutter before navigation drawer screen appear to user I have 3 screen before it

1. splash screen
2. intro slider
3. Login screen
4. NavigationDrawer

I want to close my app when user press back button in android phone from navigationdrawer screen but it will shows black screen.

I have called below called for navigation from login to drawer

```
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => NavigationDrawerDemo(),
                ),
                ModalRoute.withName('/LoginFieldForm'));
```

I called loginfieldform with

```
  Navigator.push(context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>new LoginFieldForm()));
```

Comment: can you show the code that pushes `LoginFieldForm` please? I might know what's wrong

Comment: @magicleon94 updated question

Comment: That's what I thought. Check my answer, it should be what you need

Answer (score 0):

I think you have pushed the "LoginFieldForm" with the Navigator.push method and trying to remove it using the named routes.

For Ex :

// Puching a route with Navigator.push method

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginFieldForm()),
      );
```

// Removing using the named routes.

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => NavigationDrawerDemo(),
                ),
                ModalRoute.withName('/LoginFieldForm'));
```

You can only use ModalRoute.withName() if you have added the route using named routes.

Comment: I just gave you a hint. It was not a code to implement. Still paste your methods and error logs in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your route probably has not a name set. If so, popping until the name is matched will result in popping everything, since the name you're looking for will never be found.

When you push `LoginFieldForm` ensure to pass a `settings` to the Route.

When pushing, you can do this:

```
MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: RouteSettings(name: "routeName"),
    builder: (context) => YourWidget(),
)
```

If you're within `onGenerateRoute` you already have `settings` passed as an argument to the `onGenerateRoute` function. In that case, just forward them to the `MaterialPageRoute`:

```
MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: settings, //these settings are arguments from the function
    builder: (context) => YourWidget(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To close the app you may use `exit(0)` of `dart:io` on back press.exit(0) help out to Exit the Dart VM process immediately with the given exit code.

This does not wait for any asynchronous operations to terminate. You may find more information about exit(0) [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/exit.html)

Or

```
SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
```

For more detail you may check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html)

Comment: can you please brief it little more

Answer (score 0):

Use-case: pushNamedAndRemoveUntil

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/LoginFieldForm', 
(Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```